# Python/win32com - Check if Program is Open

Tags: python, win32com

I have a script where I use win32com to interact with a COM service.  It works as intended when the program is already open.  I connect to it using win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch, then interact with a document that should already be open.  Assuming the program is already open, I can easily check if a document is open, but I'm not sure how to check if the program is already open or not.  When I use the Dispatch mentioned, it just starts the program if it isn't already open, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try win32com.client.GetActiveObject() method. This is what I use in some convenience functions I've written, this one for Excel:

```
def Excel(visible=True):
    '''Get running Excel instance if possible, else 
    return new instance. 
    '''
    try: 
        excel = win32com.client.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
        print("Running Excel instance found, returning object")

    except:
        excel = new_Excel(visible=visible)
        print("No running Excel instances, returning new instance")

    else:
        if not excel.Workbooks.Count:
            excel.Workbooks.Add(1)
        excel.Visible = visible

    return excel
```

new_Excel is just another convenience function for opening new instances of the Excel application object.

Comment: How would you handle the case when Excel isn't installed? If I use `excel  = win32.Dispatch('excel.application')`, it crashes if Excel isn't installed: `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)` How do I gracefully check first before trying to send the Dispatch?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73096832/use-python-to-detect-excel-installation