# Python Not found win32com.client.Workbooks

Tags: python, excel

```
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
for wb in excel.Workbooks:
    if wb.Name in "excel path":
        # Do something
        return
```

`excel.Workbooks` <-- Opened Excels

and i use `window10` run this script as well
but update onedrive not found Workbooks

after update `len(excel.Workbooks) => 0`
before `len(excel.Workbooks)` => `Opened Excel Count`

how to find Opened Excel??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162954/python-win32com-check-if-program-is-open

Comment: import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
excel => <win32com.gen_py.None.Application>
not found